# Is there a nice way to get a boolean from a Hashtable?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to retrieve a boolean from a hashtable... my code looks something like this:

```
Hashtable h = new Hastable();

...

h["foo"] = true;

...

object o = h["foo"];
if( o == null ) { return false; }
if( o.GetType() != typeof(bool) ) { return false; }
return (bool)o;
```

In contrast I use something like this for objects

```
return h["foo"] as MyObject;
```

Is there a nicer solution for booleans?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if a Hashtable *must* be used (or the data is typed `object` for other reasons), consider:

```
object obj = true;
bool b = (obj as bool?) ?? false;
// b -> true
```

And:

```
object obj = "hello";
bool b = (obj as bool?) ?? false;
// b -> false
```

That is, `bool?` (or `Nullable<bool>`) is happy being an `as` target (because `null` is a valid value for nullable-types) and the result is easily coalesced out (with `??`) to `bool`.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Hashtables. Those have been obsolete for seven years, since .NET 2.0 came out. Use a generic collection, like a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx), instead.

```
Dictionary<string, bool> myDict = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
myDict["foo"] = true;

bool myBool = myDict["foo"];
```

Generics are seriously wonderful. Do yourself a favor and spend a few hours looking into them. You might start [here, with MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx), and I really enjoyed Jon Skeet's book, [*C# in Depth*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182471), that covers the topic... in depth.

Comment: I need to store other non bool data in the Dictionary.

Comment: Also where does it say that Hashtable is obsolete. I looked in the MSDN docs for anything saying that it was obsolete and could not find anything.

Comment: Really? Where have you been? Hashtable is seriously obsolete. It's not deprecated, if that's what you're asking. You should not be using Hashtable for anything at all.

Comment: Care to tell us what that "non bool data" is, @MichaelAnderson?

Comment: @Kobi that has 8 references to Obsolete on that page .. all of which refer to specific members of Hashtable.

Comment: The non-bool data is an ugly blob of Strings, Objects booleans and other fun that I've inherited.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11809/discussion-between-michael-anderson-and-michael-petrotta)

Answer (score 2):

You can use extension method to help make the work more bearable:

```
public static class IDictionaryExtensions
{
    public static T? GetValue<T>(this IDictionary dictionary, object key) 
                  where T : struct
    {
        if (!dictionary.Contains(key))
            return null;
        object o = dictionary[key];
        if (o == null)
            return null;
        if (!(o is T))
            return null;
        return (T) o;
    }

    public static T GetValue<T>(this IDictionary dictionary, object key,
                                T defaultValue) where T : struct
    {
        return dictionary.GetValue<T>(key) ?? defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Use as:

```
return h.GetValue("foo", false);
```

You can easily adapt it to trow an exception at the right place, or log for missing values or type mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a generic

```
Dictionary<string, bool>
```

instead of the (obsolete) Hashtable.

Comment: The OP likely needs to use a hashtag not because he wants to. For example, Photon PUN (video game servers) requires hashtables.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool bVal = false;
object oVal;
if (hash.TryGetValue("foo", out oVal)) {
    bVal = (bool) oVal;
}
```